# How do I solve a "Wrong datatype" error in my PHP script?

Tags: php, arrays

Full Error:

```
in_array() [<a href='function.in-array'>function.in-array</a>]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/example.com/themes/example/page.tpl.php on line 22.
```

Relevant Code:

```
if (($_GET['nid']) && ($_GET['uid'] != '5')) :
    $arr = array("7916","7917","7996","7918","7990","7919","7921","7924","7925","7923","7922","8011");
    reset($arr);
    $nid = $_GET['nid'];
    // settype($nid, "integer"); 
elseif(($_GET['uid'] == '5') && ($is_front)):
    include("include_ad_front.php");    
endif;

if((in_array($nid, $arr)) && ($is_front) && (!$_GET['uid'])) {
    //code continues below...
```

Lines 3 and 5 were just my attemts to fix the problem. Line 10 is actually line 22 in this error and the one throwing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see your problem.

You have the `in_array` stuff being called after you've done your first set of `if..else` checks. Now the *first* part of your `if...else` has the array being created, but not the second.

Try moving the array somewhere *before* your first `if...else` instead of inside it.

Comment: It should't create the array unless that first issue validates, but I see what you're saying... Let me look at it and see if I get it. Just to test though, I'll try your suggestion as a band aid.

Comment: If you only want to check the array if the first `if` validates, try checking the existence of the `$arr` variable, for example `if (isset($arr) and isset($nid) and in_array($nid, $arr) ...) {`